# Jboss 4.0.5 multible jdbc drivers

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jboss

can i load multiple Jdbc drivers e.g mysql postgres etc to the application server and use the appropriate for each database ?
i have jboss 4.0.5GA and i placed the postgress jdbc driver in /server/lib where there is also oracle jdbc .The thing is that ONLY wen i remove the jdbc3 (oracle) driver the postgres works BUT if i dont remove it jboss uses PostgreSQL Native Driver .any thoughts why ?
here is my postgres-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  JBoss Server Configuration                                           -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: postgres-ds.xml 41016 2006-02-07 14:23:00Z acoliver $ -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!--  Datasource config for Postgres                                      -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->


    <datasources>
      <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>PostgresDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dvdrental</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
            <!-- sql to call when connection is created.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
            <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
            -->

            <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
            <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
            -->

          <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
          <!--<metadata>
             <type-mapping>PostgreSQL 7.2</type-mapping>
          </metadata>
          -->
      </local-tx-datasource>

    </datasources>
```

The thing is that jboss says : JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 7.3.4 JDBC3 jdbc driver build 113 but invoking displayClassInfo() shows /C:/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/remedy/lib/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar.How do i force to use the loaded driver??????

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo, but shared libs in JBoss must be placed in `server/<your conf dir>/lib`, not in the root `lib` directory.

Comment: it is a typo i have placed it under server/remedy/lib .The thing is that jboss says : JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 7.3.4 JDBC3 jdbc driver build 113 but invoking displayClassInfo() shows /C:/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/remedy/lib/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar.How do i force to use the loaded driver??????

Comment: "PostgreSQL Native Driver". Huh, what?

Comment: This sounds more like you've placed 2 different Postgresql drivers in the lib/ directory. (You might have gotten one of them from Oracle, but that wouldn't matter). Which 2 jar files(their exact filenames) have you placed where ? Where did you get theses jar files from ?